# Why does my Else Statement get an Unspecified error in my ListBox_Change()

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am trying to make a `ListBox` with various options ending with a *None*.  If *None* is selected, I want to clear the other options and just have *None* selected.  If something else gets selected, None gets cleared, and the user can select however many terms apply.

Clearing *None* works fine, but trying to clear the rest of the items when None is selected is giving me issues. I continually get the following error:

[image]

The `Listbox` in the Change() event calls itself, which is why I added the lines to make it exit if `EventsEnabled = FALSE`.  However, it doesn't want to update and clear the list, and depending on where I place any particular line, it will throw the error on that one. The two I have played with the most are the line that sets *None* to selected, and the one that re-enables events; both give me an error depending on which order I place them.

Any advice?  Am I doing some weird circular thing I need to deal with?  Is there an easier way to keep Change from calling itself?

**Relevant Code:**

```
Private Sub Reprogramming_ListBox_Change()
    ' Using this to check for a None answer. If None is selected, 
    ' it will clear out all other selections.
    ' Selecting another item will unselect None.
    If Me.EnableEvents = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    none_Index = Reprogramming_ListBox.ListCount - 1
    If None_Selected Then
        ' Check to see if the new entry is something other than None
        ' Unselect None and udpate None Flag
        If Reprogramming_ListBox.ListIndex <> none_Index Then
            None_Selected = False
            Reprogramming_ListBox.Selected(none_Index) = False
        End If
    Else
        ' Check to see if new entry is None
        If Reprogramming_ListBox.ListIndex = none_Index Then
            ' Copy-Paste this code, because I think 
            ' that will solve my unintended recursion issue
            Me.EnableEvents = False 
            Reprogramming_ListBox.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle
            Reprogramming_ListBox.Value = ""
            None_Selected = True
            Me.EnableEvents = True
            Reprogramming_ListBox.Selected(none_Index) = True
            Reprogramming_ListBox.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
            ' If it is None, clear out other entries
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I can't visualize what you're trying. Do you mean you want to change the list shown in the listbox depending on what you select at runtime?

Comment: Are you trying to check `Application.EnableEvents` or have you created a variable called `EnableEvents` for this userform?

Comment: @barrow I read somewhere that Application.EnableEvents does not disable UserForm events.  It showed the example that I coded, where you create a global, set it to false when you want to do something, and then set it back.  If the Application will disable UserForm events, I will use that instead.  And L42, yes, that's pretty much it.  I want to clear the other selections if None or Other is selected, and if one or more items are selected, I want to clear the null option.